# How can I remove the cart from a Big Cartel website?

Tags: bigcartel

I am trying to customize my site so you have to contact me before buying. If I change my "Add to Cart" button from product page to be an "order" button that takes you to the contact form, this could possibly work (I am only having one issue, which I will post separately).

I can't find the "cart" anywhere in the css files to delete the cart or make invisible. Thanks very much for any help or advice you can offer.

Comment: The solution to this largely depends on what Big Cartel theme you're using, Can you provide that or your store's address?

Comment: I purchased the Saturn theme from Theme Fiend, and they haven't responded to any of my emails. Thank you for responding. Saturn is a customization of the Neat theme, from what I understand. shoplarry dot com

Answer (score 0):

For this specific Theme Fiend theme, you can hide the cart display (for both desktop and mobile) from the header area by adding this code to the bottom of Customize Design > Advanced > CSS:

```
#minicart-search-box #minicart, #minicart.mobile-minicart {
  display: none;
}
```